# How to clean a CSV file for reading text in double quotes as one column

Tags: bash, scala, csv, apache-spark

I am working with a dataset which has crime data for Chicago using Scala and Apache Spark

There are a few lines where multiple values are separated by a comma and put in double quotes. Is there a way to clean the data so that the text under double quotes can be read as one column

The text is below and the columns in bold is what I want to read as a single column

```
10366565,HZ102660,01/03/2016 01:50:00 PM,020XX S WABASH AVE,1310,CRIMINAL DAMAGE,TO PROPERTY,**“SCHOOL, PRIVATE, BUILDING”**,false,false,0131,001,3,33,14,1177070,1890608,2016,01/10/2016 08:46:55 AM,41.855167994,-87.625552607,"(41.855167994, -87.625552607)"
```

The desired output would be something like below so that the text under quote could be read as a single string by removing the commas:

```
10366565,HZ102660,01/03/2016 01:50:00 PM,020XX S WABASH AVE,1310,CRIMINAL DAMAGE,TO PROPERTY,**“SCHOOL|PRIVATE|BUILDING”**,false,false,0131,001,3,33,14,1177070,1890608,2016,01/10/2016 08:46:55 AM,41.855167994,-87.625552607,**"(41.855167994|-87.625552607)"**
```

Is there a way to do it in Scala or transform it into a new file using shell scripting?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus done the edit

Comment: `sed 's/, /|/g' file`?

Comment: In the future, please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Glad that you got a quick solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Spark by default takes quoted string (regardless of whether it contains commas) from CSV file as a single column, hence if you want you can process the quoted content after it's read into a DataFrame:

Sample CSV data:

```
10366565,01/03/2016 01:50:00 PM,"SCHOOL, PRIVATE, BUILDING"
10366700,01/04/2016 12:30:00 PM,"SCHOOL, PRIVATE, BUILDING"
```

Sample code:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("/path/to/csvfile")

+--------+----------------------+-------------------------+
|_c0     |_c1                   |_c2                      |
+--------+----------------------+-------------------------+
|10366565|01/03/2016 01:50:00 PM|SCHOOL, PRIVATE, BUILDING|
|10366700|01/04/2016 12:30:00 PM|SCHOOL, PRIVATE, BUILDING|
+--------+----------------------+-------------------------+

// A UDF function that converts ",\s*" to "|"
def commaToPipe = udf( (s: String) =>
  """,\s*""".r.replaceAllIn(s, "|")
)

df.select($"_c0", commaToPipe($"_c2")).show(truncate=false)
+--------+-----------------------+
|_c0     |UDF(_c2)               |
+--------+-----------------------+
|10366565|SCHOOL|PRIVATE|BUILDING|
|10366700|SCHOOL|PRIVATE|BUILDING|
+--------+-----------------------+
```

[UPDATE]

As pointed out by a commenter, using `regexp_replace` would eliminate the need for UDF:

```
df.select($"_c0", regexp_replace($"_c2", """,\s*""", "|"))
```

Comment: `regexp_replace` would work just fine instead of the UDF.

Comment: Thanks @philantrovert, Spark's native function is certainly preferred.  Answer updated.